# Wix Copy component to many folders in Custom Action

Tags: c#, wix

How to copy one file in setup project to many folders in target machine?

Yet I thought up like this:

```cs
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey hkcu = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser;
        string keyname = "SOFTWARE\\SomeApp\\ExtPaths";
        String keyValue = hkcu.GetValue("Path templates").ToString();

        List<String> paths = ParsePaths(keyValue);
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            File.Copy(/*maybe component?*/);
        }
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }

    private static List<string> ParsePaths(string keyValue)
    {
        return keyValue.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    }
```

I don't want to install component in the programm folder, I need to put my file in my setup to the previously found paths. Should I do it in the Custom Action? Or should I do it differently?

Comment: You might be stuck with that registry entry but consider giving some pushback to the application design; The goal shouldn't be to dump complexity on the installer because it seems to make the application simpler or allows deferring the installer design until after the application is complete. See [HeroicProgramming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HeroicProgramming).

Comment: The files are a templates. And I can not install them until I know the path to the templates have another program on target computer.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom action for this is unnecessary and would mean that you would also have to manually remove the files as well (as MSI won't be aware of them).

From memory you should create one `Component` for each file (or one for all of them, but it's a better practice to do them individually if you intend to patch or merge).

E.g.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="D.WEBSITE_INSTALL">
   <Component Id="myComponentId" Guid="8853AEFC-CF85-4D20-89D2-CCB59593B973">
      <File Id="someFileId" KeyPath="yes" Source="SomePath\SomeFile.ext" />
   </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

And you then should be able to refer to it within another Directory/ComponentGroup/Feature. E.g.

```
<ComponentGroup Id="SomeGroupId">
      <ComponentRef Id="myComponentId"/>
</ComponentGroup>
```

That should be the general idea, apologies this is based upon one of my installers and i haven't tested this.

Comment: i don't know installation paths for file "SomeFile.ext" untill the setup is started. Files may remain after removing the program.

Comment: You don't need to know the installation paths they just need a default. In my example above D.WEBSITE_INSTALL is a directory, the path would be determined when you run the installer. However if you need the files to remain after uninstallation then I would recommend using a custom action

Comment: "the path would be determined when you run the installer" No. The pathS. I don't know how many them.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can configure as many paths as you wish in the installer and store them in properties. Or if they all live in the same root folder, as a single property as above.